# How to access the deployed contract's address from Truffle JS tests?

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-contract

I've written a test that involves returning the token balance that the contract itself holds. In the contract source file I would access the balance using the function `getBalanceOf(this)`. However, when I include `instance.getBalanceOf(this)` in my JS tests, I get a `new BigNumber() is not a number` error.

I've narrowed it down to my tests not having access to the deployed contract's address. I know you can access it in Solidity tests using the DeployedAddresses.sol library, but is there any way to do it in JS tests?

Cheers,
Pryce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const TokenArtifact = require('./../../build/contracts/YourToken.json');

var Token = contract(TokenArtifact);
Token.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);
var tokenInstance = await Token.deployed();
```

Now,

```
tokenInstance.address
```

Will give you, your deployed contract's address.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is `instance.address`

Answer (score 2):

When you run `truffle test ./path/to/test.js`, truffle automatically runs the migration script first. This means you can reference those deployed contracts through the artifacts global like so:

```
const ContractInstance = artifacts.require('ContractInstance.sol')

ContractInstance.deployed()
.then(inst => {
  // do some stuff
})
```

If you are simply doing a getter request, you should `.call()` the method instead of making a tx. `contract.method.call()` will actually return the value where as the transaction `contract.method()` will return a big tx object.

```
ContractInstance.deployed()
.then(inst => {
  inst.getBalanceOf.call()
}).then(balance => {
  console.log(balance.toNumber()) // 33
})
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I've got the contract's instance saved to a variable which I'm using throughout. My getBalanceOf is a also a call, I just neglected to mention it. What I'm really looking for is what to pass as an argument to `instance.getBalanceOf.call(address)` where address is the address of the deployed contract. I appreciate any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

@PryceTurner :"What I'm really looking for is what to pass as an argument to instance.getBalanceOf.call(address) where address is the address of the deployed contract. I appreciate any insight you can offer."

The answer you're looking for is: **instance.getBalanceOf.call(ContractInstance.address)**

Notes:

- ContactInstance being what you defined up top: const ContractInstance = artifacts.require('ContractInstance.sol')
- In ContactInstance.address 'address' is case sensitive